# How to create custom warnings for Xaml in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, compiler-warnings, visual-studio-2022

As with the Roslyn CodeAnalyzers I want to be able to analyze Xaml and generate warnings with possible fixes.

I came across RapidXaml which supports VS19, but not VS22.

My goal is the following:

1. Inspect Xaml
2. Generate warning in VS22 based on specific requirements
3. Finally, provide code fixes via Quick Actions (light bulb) in VS22

Example how it should look like:

[Xaml tag with warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2vfR.png)

Any suggestions or nuget-packages are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix#create-analyzer-registrations)